Trying to figure out what type of packages Launchpad contains
I have a question regarding what type of package can be downloaded from Launchpad.
As an example I have the following package https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debconf/1.5.86ubuntu1
On the download section I can see the following URL's:
debconf_1.5.86ubuntu1.tar.xz
debconf_1.5.86ubuntu1.dsc
These are binary packages for Ubuntu operating system or are the source codes?
I understand that also we can find other types of URL as in the following example: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lazr.restfulclient/0.14.4-1
Where we have the below links and for my understanding .orig.tar.gz is the original source code and debian.tar.xz is the binary package that is used to install that specific package on Ubuntu.
lazr.restfulclient_0.14.4-1.dsc 1.8 KiB
lazr.restfulclient_0.14.4.orig.tar.gz   60.8 KiB
lazr.restfulclient_0.14.4.orig.tar.gz.asc   833 bytes
lazr.restfulclient_0.14.4-1.debian.tar.xz   8.8 KiB
Can someone explain me the terminology for these extensions? I've tried to find some information's online but I didn't understand them to clearly.

https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/SourcePackage
